# Alljoyn framework - Java - Signals . BUS_NO_SUCH_INTERFACE

Tags: java, android, signals, dbus, alljoyn

It's a quite specific question but after days stuck in the same place and not getting any response in the Alljoyn forum, I decided to post it here. Maybe someone worked with this framework.

I am doing a project and I need the use of the signal mechanish that Alljoyn framework provides. However, I do need the signals inside a session and the example provides in the api core is sessionless.

In my case I need the service (server) to raise a signal and the client to receive it, but I am getting this error. Following the api samples, I managed to create a simple app that exchange messages through the methods defined in the interface, so I know that the communication is working. In this case, the service waits until the client connects and the send the signal. The client joins the session and right after register the signal and I am getting the BUS_NO_SUCH_INTERFACE error. I tried also to register after and before sending the signal, same problem. I think that for some reason the client does not find the bussignalhandler but I don't know why. I also put it in an external class and it didn't work.

I'm following the example in the core api guide:
https://allseenalliance.org/developers/develop/api-guide/core/android

This is the part where the service register and emit the signal:

```
SignalEmitter emitter = new SignalEmitter(mySignalInterface, joinerName, 
   sessionId,
SignalEmitter.GlobalBroadcast.Off);
myInterface = emitter.getInterface(SampleInterface.class);
// Emitting signals myInterface.buttonClicked(1); 
myInterface.playerPosition(12, 1, -24);
```

However, in that example, I can't see a definition for `myInterface`. and I know it is not a mistake and they meant `mySignalInterface` because the method `getInterface` asks for an interface object and `mySignalInterface` is a class which implements that interface.

I put here the example I created and I'll upload the files in case someone wants to try them.

```
@BusInterface(name = "org.alljoyn.bus.samples.simple.SimpleInterface")
public interface SimpleInterface {

    @BusMethod
    String Ping(String inStr) throws BusException;

    @BusSignal
    public void playerPosition(int x, int y, int z) throws BusException;
}
```

Service:

Class inside the service to implement the signal and method

```
class SimpleService implements SimpleInterface, BusObject {

    public String Ping(String inStr) {
    mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_PING, inStr));
        return inStr;
    }

    public void playerPosition(int x, int y, int z) { /* no implementation needed here*/}

}
```

Here part of the code that makes the connection in the service:

```
case CONNECT: {
    org.alljoyn.bus.alljoyn.DaemonInit.PrepareDaemon(getApplicationContext());

    mBus = new BusAttachment(getPackageName(), BusAttachment.RemoteMessage.Receive);

    mBus.registerBusListener(new BusListener());

    Status status = mBus.registerBusObject(mSimpleService, "/SimpleService");
    if (status != Status.OK) {...}

    status = mBus.connect();
    logStatus("BusAttachment.connect()", status);
    if (status != Status.OK) {...}

    int flag = 0;

    status = mBus.requestName(SERVICE_NAME, flag);
    logStatus(String.format("BusAttachment.requestName(%s, 0x%08x)", SERVICE_NAME, flag), status);
    if (status == Status.OK) {
        status = mBus.advertiseName(SERVICE_NAME, SessionOpts.TRANSPORT_ANY);
        logStatus(String.format("BusAttachement.advertiseName(%s)", SERVICE_NAME), status);
        if (status != Status.OK) {...}
    }

    Mutable.ShortValue contactPort = new Mutable.ShortValue(CONTACT_PORT);

    SessionOpts sessionOpts = new SessionOpts();
    sessionOpts.traffic = SessionOpts.TRAFFIC_MESSAGES;
    sessionOpts.isMultipoint = false;
    sessionOpts.proximity = SessionOpts.PROXIMITY_ANY;

    sessionOpts.transports = SessionOpts.TRANSPORT_ANY + SessionOpts.TRANSPORT_WFD;

    status = mBus.bindSessionPort(contactPort, sessionOpts, new SessionPortListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean acceptSessionJoiner(short sessionPort, String joiner, SessionOpts sessionOpts) {
        return sessionPort == CONTACT_PORT;
        }

        @Override
        public void sessionJoined(short port, int id, String s) {
        sessionId = id; joinerName = s; sessionEstablished = true;
        }
    });
    logStatus(String.format("BusAttachment.bindSessionPort(%d, %s)",
                        contactPort.value, sessionOpts.toString()), status);
    if (status != Status.OK) {...}

    try {
        while (!sessionEstablished) {
        Thread.sleep(10);
        }

        SignalEmitter emitter = new SignalEmitter(mSimpleService, joinerName, sessionId, SignalEmitter.GlobalBroadcast.Off);
        SimpleInterface myInterface = emitter.getInterface(SimpleInterface.class);
        myInterface.playerPosition(12,1,1);
    }
    catch (BusException ex) {...  }
}
```

Client:

```
/*On create of the activity which has a button and a text view to send text to the server */
mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL
            && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        /* Call the remote object's Ping method. */
        Message msg = mBusHandler.obtainMessage(BusHandler.PING,
                                                view.getText().toString());
        mBusHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
    return true;
}
});

private static final String SERVICE_NAME = "org.alljoyn.bus.samples.simple";
private static final short CONTACT_PORT=42;

private BusAttachment mBus;
private ProxyBusObject mProxyObj;
private SimpleInterface mSimpleInterface;


case CONNECT: {
    org.alljoyn.bus.alljoyn.DaemonInit.PrepareDaemon(getApplicationContext());

    mBus = new BusAttachment(getPackageName(), BusAttachment.RemoteMessage.Receive);


    mBus.registerBusListener(new BusListener() {
    @Override
    public void foundAdvertisedName(String name, short transport, String namePrefix) {

        if(!mIsConnected) {
        Message msg = obtainMessage(JOIN_SESSION);
        msg.arg1 = transport;
        msg.obj = name;
        sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }
    });


    Status status = mBus.connect();
    logStatus("BusAttachment.connect()", status);
    if (Status.OK != status) {...}


    status = mBus.findAdvertisedName(SERVICE_NAME);
    logStatus(String.format("BusAttachement.findAdvertisedName(%s)", SERVICE_NAME), status);
    if (Status.OK != status) {...}

    break;
}
case (JOIN_SESSION): {

    if (mIsStoppingDiscovery) {
        break;
    }

    short contactPort = CONTACT_PORT;
    SessionOpts sessionOpts = new SessionOpts();
    sessionOpts.transports = (short)msg.arg1;
    Mutable.IntegerValue sessionId = new Mutable.IntegerValue();

    Status status = mBus.joinSession((String) msg.obj, contactPort, sessionId, sessionOpts, new SessionListener() {
    @Override
    public void sessionLost(int sessionId, int reason) {
        mIsConnected = false;
        logInfo(String.format("MyBusListener.sessionLost(sessionId = %d, reason = %d)", sessionId,reason));
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MESSAGE_START_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
    }
    });


    if (status == Status.OK) {

        mProxyObj =  mBus.getProxyBusObject(SERVICE_NAME,
               "/SimpleService",
               sessionId.value,
               new Class<?>[] { SimpleInterface.class });


        mSimpleInterface =  mProxyObj.getInterface(SimpleInterface.class);

        mSessionId = sessionId.value;
        mIsConnected = true;
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MESSAGE_STOP_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
    }
    break;
    status = mBus.registerSignalHandlers(this);
    if (status != Status.OK) {...}
}
case PING: {
    try {
    if (mSimpleInterface != null) {

        sendUiMessage(MESSAGE_PING, msg.obj);
        String reply = mSimpleInterface.Ping((String) msg.obj);
        sendUiMessage(MESSAGE_PING_REPLY, reply);
    } catch {...}
}
...here some more code...
@BusSignalHandler(iface="org.alljoyn.bus.samples.simple.SimpleInterface", signal="playerPosition")
public void playerPosition(int x, int y, int z) {
sendUiMessage(MESSAGE_POST_TOAST, "Signal captured");
}
```

In this example, I have my client which has a textview where I can add text and send a ping to the server. This is working if I get rid of the registering signal part. I tried to do it as the api core says, with the Thread.sleep but doesn't work either.

Here I add the code of both of my applications (client & server) based on the samples that are in the alljoyn api. 
https://github.com/JavierT/Alljoyn_signal_sample

Please let me know if you have some doubts, it was hard to put all the information in one post. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should solve your problem

[Alljoyn BusSignalHandler](https://allseenalliance.org/docs/api/java/org/alljoyn/bus/annotation/BusSignalHandler.html#iface%28%29)

either of the following may be used to annotate a signal handler:

```
 @BusSignalHandler(iface = "org.sample.MyInterface", signal = "MySignal")
 public void handleSignal(String str)
 {
 }

 @BusSignalHandler(iface = "org.myapp.IMyInterface", signal = "EmitMySignal")
 public void handleSignal(String str)
 {
 }
```

The first example may be used succesfully when `IMyInterface` is known to the `BusAttachment` via a previous call to `BusAttachment.registerBusObject(BusObject, String)` or `BusAttachment.getProxyBusObject(String, String, int, Class[])`.

The second example may be used succesfully when `IMyInterface` is unknown to the `BusAttachment`.
using the second example should solve your problem.

Also, in your Client program as per the link provided above,

```
@BusSignalHandler(iface="org.alljoyn.bus.samples.simple.SimpleInterface", signal="playerPosition")
```

should be replaced with

```
@BusSignalHandler(iface="org.alljoyn.bus.samples.simpleclient.SimpleInterface", signal="playerPosition")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `registerSignalHandlers` you must pass an object that implements the interface `SimpleInterface` and the method `playerPosition` will be called in that object when you receives a signal.

I believe (I've read the code quickly, I hope I'm not wrong) that you pass your `BusHandler` object, which does not implements `SimpleInterface`.

Comment: I check my code and i saw I didn't add the implementation of the code in the client (in the question). This implementation is inside the `BusHandler` and that's why I send `this` in `RegisterSignalHandlers`.   I also tried to put the implementation of the BusSignal in another class and pass it to `RegisterSignalHandlers` and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please change :

```
private static final String SERVICE_NAME = "org.alljoyn.bus.samples.simple";
```

to

"`org.alljoyn.bus.samples.simple.SimpleInterface`" as you have interface name ,

both should be same . as when the Get method of BusObject is called the interface names does not match.